# JavaScript - How to merge a complex nested object using another as reference to iterate?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have an object with multiple keys in the shape of:

```
{
    '.[key1].[key2].[key3]': {},
    '.[key1].[key2].[key3].[key4]': {},
    '.[key1].[key2].[key3].[key5]': {},
}
```

Given this example is pretty obvious that I generated this code using some reference in order to create these keys.

Below is the reference object

```
const invoiceShape = {
    'cfdi\\:CdfiRelacionados': {
      'tfd\\:CfdiRelacionado': {},
    },
    'cfdi\\:Emisor': {},
    'cfdi\\:Receptor': {},
    'cfdi\\:Conceptos': {
      'cfdi\\:Concepto': {
        'cfdi\\:Impuestos': {
          'cfdi\\:Traslados': {
            'cfdi\\:Traslado': {},
          },
          'cfdi\\:Retenciones': {
            'cfdi\\:Retencion': {},
          },
          'cfdi\\:InformacionAduanera': {},
          'cfdi\\:CuentaPredial': {},
          'cfdi\\:Parte': {
            'cfdi\\:InformacionAduanera': {},
          },
        },
      },
    },
    'cfdi\\:Complemento': {
      'tfd\\:TimbreFiscalDigital': {},
    },
    'cfdi\\:Addenda': {},
  };
```

So, my object looks like this

```
const invoiceParsed = {
    '.cfdi\\:Conceptos.cfdi\\:Concepto.cfdi\\:Impuestos': {},
    '.cfdi\\:Conceptos.cfdi\\:Concepto.cfdi\\:Impuestos.cfdi\\:Traslados': {},
    '.cfdi\\:Conceptos.cfdi\\:Concepto.cfdi\\:Impuestos.cfdi\\:Retenciones': {},
}
```

The **invoiceShape** object has empty values on the keys, but now that the **invoiceParsed** object is filled I want it to fill the **invoiceShape** as well, I figured out that parsing every nested level spliting the "." in the keys of **invoiceParsed** is a more effective way to iterate over the reference object, but if I iterate over the `'cfdi\\:Conceptos'` key a second time I just overwrite the key value, instead of merging it

I'm not posting any code on the iteration, because I want read your ideas,  algorithms or packages you would use as lodash for example

Comment: Please give sample input, sample output *in the question itself*, clearly labelled as such. It's not at all clear what the point of what you posted is, or the link to the XML (offsite!!). What's up with all the escaping? What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: *"I'm not posting any code on the iteration, because I want read your ideas"* That's not really the way this site works.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first question, thanks for your patience in advance, and I'll crack how to ask this question no matter how long this take

Comment: I don't understand the problem of overwriting, but if the values are in the second object structure, why do you still the need the first? Can't you just regenerate it from the second? What is there to merge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/docs) for something like this, although [partial.lenses](https://github.com/calmm-js/partial.lenses) is another excellent tool for working with deeply nested data.

Here are two working solutions. The first uses several functions from Ramda. The second is mostly vanilla JS with only two functions from Ramda:

```js
const shape = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: {}
    }
  },
  d: {
    e: {
      f: {
        g: {}
      }
    }
  },
  h: {}
}

const parsed = {
  'a': { v: 1 },
  'a.b': { v: 2 },
  'a.b.c': { v: 3 },
  'd': { v: 4 },
  'd.e': { v: 5 },
  'd.e.f': { v: 6 },
  'd.e.f.g': { v: 7 },
  'h': { v: 8 }
}

const fillShapeWithParsed = s =>
  R.pipe(
    R.toPairs,
    R.reduce(
      (acc, [k, v]) =>
        R.over(R.lensPath(k.split('.')), R.merge(v), acc),
        s
    )
  )

console.log(
  fillShapeWithParsed(shape)(parsed)
)

const merge = x => y => ({ ...y, ...x })

const fillShapeWithParsedVanilla = s => p =>
  Object.entries(p).reduce(
    (acc, [k, v]) =>
      R.over(R.lensPath(k.split('.')), merge(v), acc),
      s
  )

console.log(
  fillShapeWithParsedVanilla(shape)(parsed)
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

For a hybrid solution using Ramda and partial.lenses together, just swap out the line in the example that begins `R.over(` with this one:

```
L.modify(k.split('.'), R.merge(v), acc)
```

Comment: Glad I could help! Lenses offer a powerful abstraction for working with deeply nested data. This is example is just scratching the surface. Also, if you have quick questions about Ramda or partial.lenses, each has a gitter room: https://gitter.im/ramda/ramda & https://gitter.im/calmm-js/chat . There are also `ramda` and `partial.lenses` tags here on StackOverflow.